# modificar grafico angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart

amigos estou tentando resolver um problema o qual venho buscando solução em alguns foruns e nenhum me ajuda especificamente.

eu tenho um grafico usando piechart que renderiza um grafico pizza. Porem ele fnciona com valores fixos, só que eu tenho um retorno do banco e monto um json, a pergunta é como faço para colocar todos os valores do json no piechart? se eu usar um array ele retorna somente o ultimo valor. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 500,
            x: function (d) {
                return d.key;
            },
            y: function (d) {
                return d.y;
            },
            showLabels: true,
            duration: 500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
            legend: {
                margin: {
                    top: 5,
                    right: 35,
                    bottom: 5,
                    left: 0
                }
            }
        }
    };


    $scope.sistemas = [
        {
            key: results.dados[0].key,
            y: results.dados[0].y
        }
    ];


});
```

o codigo Json que retorna  é esse abaixo

```
{"dados":[
      {"y":1,"key":"REQUISICAO"},
      {"y":1,"key":"SITEF"},
      {"y":1,"key":"NetSms"},
      {"y":2,"key":"CA"}
]}
```

Comment: Qual a biblioteca do gráfico que vc usa?

Comment: chart.js  PieCtrl do angular